# How to add button for every field when retrieving data from a database

Tags: php, html

I have looked everywhere for this question, perhaps I'm just not phrasing it correctly.

I have a page displaying various products, the table is called items. There in my fields I have all the information and images to display on the page, this works fine. Now I want to be able to press a button to add the item to cart, I have the code below where I access the data.

```
<div class="col-md-5">
 <h2 style="font-size:25px;"> <?=$items['title'];?></h2>
 <img src="<?=$items['image'];?> "width='300' height='500'/>
 <p style="font-size:20px;" class = "lprice">GBP <?= $items['price'];?></p>
</div>
```

Now that I have done that, my question is how can I add a button for every time a result is displayed and have that button linked with that item, I appreciate this may no be as straight forward as I am phrasing this, but just looking for some help.

Thanks

Comment: Does your items have some unique id

Comment: Yes they do have unique ID's: 1,2,3,4 etc

Comment: Can you also provide full code

Comment: Code: https://github.com/20207957/website

Comment: Database: https://imgur.com/a/lfVsuVO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two ways, either way, you need a primary key (eg: id) in your items table which will hold a unique number for each of your items.
After that, you print your id along with everything else inside a button or inside an `a` tag. Like

```
<div class="col-md-5">
 <h2 style="font-size:25px;"> <?=$items['title'];?></h2>
 <img src="<?=$items['image'];?> "width='300' height='500'/>
 <p style="font-size:20px;" class = "lprice">GBP <?= $items['price'];?></p>
 <a class="btn btn-primary" href="add_to_cart.php?id=<?=$items['id'];?>">Add to Cart</a>
</div>
```

Now inside your `add_to_cart.php` file, you can receive the id of the products like this `$product_id = $_GET['id'];`

Once you have the id of the product, you can process the rest on the add_to_cart.php file and redirect the user back to the previous page with a success or error message.

This way, we passed the id using a URL parameter. The second way is to pass the id using a form. I just wanted to let you that this method exists. I hope this helps. If you have any doubt, feel free to ask in the comment section.

Comment: Thank you, this helps me a lot, once I have it in the add_to_cart.php would it be a good idea to store it in a session variable?

Comment: Yeah, if you're building your cart functionality using session variables, that would be okay. And if you're building your cart functionality using the database, you can save it in the database from add_to_cart.php and then save the error or success message in the session variable and show it from the main page.